# I have a SQL query to get sum of column of last 13 months, How do I add zero is any month is missing

Tags: mysql, addition, date-format, zero, dateadd

I have a payments table, Where I update the subscription renewal date and amount, now I have a query to select previous 13 months sum of amounts column, But how do I add zero if no payment data is available for any month in the selected last 13 months of record.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, "%b - %Y") AS month, SUM(intPaymentAmount) as usd13mon FROM `tbl_pi_payment` WHERE strCurrencyCode = 'USD' and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate <= NOW() and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 13 month) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, "%Y-%m")

month      usd13mon
Oct - 2018 55
Dec - 2018 79
Jan - 2019 16
Feb - 2019 93
Mar - 2019 80
Apr - 2019 83
May - 2019 34
Jun - 2019 23
Jul - 2019 25
Aug - 2019 37
Sep - 2019 17
Oct - 2019 44
```

In the above-mentioned output the nov 2018 month is missing as there was data available in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You may try introducing a calendar table which represents every month which you want to appear in your report:

```
SELECT
    m.my,
    COALESCE(SUM(t.intPaymentAmount), 0) AS usd13mon
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Nov - 2018' AS my UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dec - 2018' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jan - 2019' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'Nov - 2019'
) m
LEFT JOIN tbl_pi_payment t
    ON m.my = DATE_FORMAT(t.dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, '%b - %Y') AND
       t.strCurrencyCode = 'USD' AND
       t.dtSubscriptionRenewalDate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 13 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    m.my;
```